# Box plot categories from two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Sorry for basic question, I am new to R. 
I would like to plot a box with subcategories and then with measurements taken over time.

For example I have tried this:

```
boxplot(field_data$week_1~field_data$field, ylab= 'number of infected plants')
```

This gives me two box plots (field is either ‘north’ or ‘south’). I want to split each boxplot into two boxplots by "position" variable (1 or 2). Is there a way to make it so that I will still have a plot with 2 main categories defined by "field", but then each will consist of two boxplots defined by "position" variable. I would also then like to plot the results from the ‘week_2’ readings next to the 'week_1' set of box plots. All of the data is in one df. I have other variables ('beds' and 'rows') with different levels too that categorise the measurements taken.

I have tried with ggplot but not sure how to do this or if this is the right function.

Thank you.

Comment: You could fiddle around with the formula interface  like this: `boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl + mtcars$am)`. In the future, provide a reproducible example, using (for example) built-in datasets like this.

Comment: Thank you lmo! I used this example and it works great :)